# Is there an ansible module to take snapshot on disk Azure

Tags: azure, ansible, cloud

I'm just getting started with Ansible. I've created simple vms with azure module on Ansible.
Now, I'm trying to take a snapshot on azure disk with ansible.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a module according to the [module list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/list_of_cloud_modules.html#azure). You can use [azure_rm_resource](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/azure_rm_resource_module.html#azure-rm-resource-module) module to perform a custom post request to Azure with Ansible. [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/snapshots/createorupdate) an API call you should mimic with Ansible

Answer (score 0):

---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:

  - name: Create a snapshot by copying an existing managed disk.
    azure_rm_snapshot:
    resource_group: ****
    name: mySnapshot
    location: centralindia
    creation_data:
    create_option: Copy
    source_id: '******'

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.